# Long text in multirow

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

I have long text in a multirow cell. And the text takes more rows than the rows in the second column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[H]{|p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline
\multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text}} & \tiny 11 \tabularnewline \cline{2-2}
 & \tiny 11 \tabularnewline \cline{1-2}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I get this:
[image]

How can I fix it? I generate table automatically, and I do not know how many lines of text in the multirow cell takes. So I can not manually add blank lines in the second column.

**Update for Bernard** When I compile this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline%
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{\linewidth}%[24pt]
{\centering \scriptsize \textbf{Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long}}}
& \Gape[12pt]{\scriptsize 11} \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2}
& \Gape[12pt]{\scriptsize 11} \tabularnewline
 \cline{1-2}
\end{longtable}\bigskip

{\normalsize
\begin{longtable}{|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline%
\multirowcell{8}{\parbox{\linewidth}
{\centering \textbf{Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long}}}
&\multirowcell{4}{11} \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2}
& \multirowcell{4}{11} \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline
 \cline{1-2}
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

I see this result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not a full answer, just a couple of suggestions. First, f everything in the `longtable` is going to be set in `\tiny` size (at least that's the way it looks in your MWE), it may be best to provide that directive *before* the start of the `longtable` environment; otherwise you'll get serious problems with baselines not lining up. Second, have you thought about inserting "struts" (invisible vertical bars) in the cells of the second column?

Comment: I agree about the moment with tiny.

I do not know how much you need to add an empty space in the second column. Table is generated automatically in the program.

Comment: Does the program output change every time, or is it fixed from run to run?

Comment: Сhange every time. I do not know in advance the contents of cells. The length of the text of each may be different. The optimal solution would be to have a multirow cell automatically stretched to the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable,calc}

\newlength{\MyLength}

\newcommand{\Multirow}[3]{%
    \setlength{\MyLength}{%
        \heightof{
            \begin{minipage}[b]{#2}
            #3
            \end{minipage}
        }
    }
    \global\MyLength=\MyLength
    \multirow{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\newcommand{\Myrule}[1][.5]{\rule[-#1\MyLength]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

{\tiny
\begin{longtable}[H]{|p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline
\Multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering \tiny \textbf{Long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text}} &
11 \Myrule[.55]\tabularnewline \cline{2-2}
 & 11 \Myrule[.3]\tabularnewline \cline{1-2}
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good decision, but the decision should be set variable \MyLength manually. Can we find \MyLength if we know text in cell?

Comment: It is precisly my problem. The \Multirow command should set \Mylength with the heigt of the cell. I asked how to use it globally. Then you don't have to set it manually.

Comment: Ok, I find how to have a global length.

Answer (score 4):

A solution could be to use the `\Gape` command (from the  `makecell` package) to increase the height of the cells in the second column that correspond to the `\multirow` in the first column. The value of the optional argument has to be determined experimentally, as it depends on the font/ fontsize. You also have to put the long text in a  \parbox inside multirow.

Another solution, also with `makecell` consists in making both cells in the second column `\multirowcell`s, of the (same) relevant number of rows, and the long text a `\multirowcell` of twice this number of rows.

Both solutions are illustrated in the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline%
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{\linewidth}%
{\centering \scriptsize \textbf{Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long}}}
& \Gape[12pt]{\scriptsize 11} \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2}
& \Gape[12pt]{\scriptsize 11} \tabularnewline
 \cline{1-2}
\end{longtable}\bigskip

{\normalsize
\begin{longtable}{|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|m{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
\caption{Title}
\tabularnewline\hline%
\multirowcell{8}{\parbox{\linewidth}
{\centering \textbf{Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long}}}
&\multirowcell{4}{11} \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-2}
& \multirowcell{4}{11} \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline & \tabularnewline
 \cline{1-2}
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is package \usepackage{fourier} nessesery? With this package, an error occurs. No service is no error, but the cell does not stretch.

Comment: No, not at all, it's just there because I don't like Computer Modern. But of course, the numerical values will have to be adapted. However, what you tell me is strange. Did you compile the code alone, or did you use it in a document with its own preamble?

Comment: I copy all code in new document and delete string ```\usepackage{fourier}``` only. I use TeXstudio 2.6.2 + MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7. In post I added screenshot of result code.

Comment: I see. You'll have to increase the value in `Gape` for the first solution (16 pt?) and the number of rows for the second solution (one more should do the trick).